# What is a working definition of "layout" as it pertains to HTML?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I've been tasked with explaining to a few colleagues why you shouldn't always use <table> elements for positioning things in HTML. There are a lot of places on the internet where it says you shouldn't use <table> elements for layout but none actually provide a definition for what "layout" is. So, it's easy to tell someone "don't use tables for layout" but if we don't actually provide a working definition of "layout" that *cannot functionally* include <table> elements, then what's stopping that person from coming up with their own definition?

Here's one definition of "layout" from geeksforgeeks.org (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-layout/):

> Page layout is the part of graphic design that deals with the
>   arrangement of visual elements on a page.

The problem with this definition is that <table> elements can indeed be used to arrange visual elements on a page, so it is confusing to beginners when they're told they shouldn't use <table> elements--the definition itself doesn't seem to exclude them, so why not?

Here's another assertion from w3schools.com that you shouldn't use <table> elements for layout, but it fails to define "layout" (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp):

> The <table> element was not designed to be a layout tool! The
>   purpose of the <table> element is to display tabular data. So, do not
>   use tables for your page layout!

Once again, what is "layout" to a beginner? Technically, everything on the page could be considered layout, even the tabular data parts, since tabular data can also be presented using <div> elements. Therefore, saying "don't use tables for layout" means nothing and isn't helpful, because layout is everything on the page (even tabular data is layout; it's data displayed in a tabular layout).

In closing, I'm curious if there is a definition of "layout" that *cannot* be interpreted as being anything on a web page. If there is no definition, perhaps we can formulate one here.

Comment: @Alohci you're right--which is why I think it's silly to say "don't use tables for layout"--it means nothing because layout is everything on a page (tabular data is data presented in a tabular layout, etc)

Comment: The real question here, "why shouldn't we use tables for layout" is because CSS does not define how tables should be handled layout-wise. There *is* a [CSS Tables spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-tables/), but it is only a working draft, and has been for years. Tables have a semantic meaning (tabular data). Abusing that semantic meaning to force content to appear where you want is doable, but not recommended because it causes the table to lose that semantic meaning, which can have real implications for people who use assistive technology to access your webpage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to define layout to exclude tables so that tables aren't used for layout. Those aren't the same thing.

Like it or not, layout is the placing of elements on a page or screen. The term comes from when pieces of type, photos, rules (lines), and other elements were pasted into position on a layout sheet that was printed with grid lines. You literally laid out the page.

The reason to avoid tables is because there are better ways in HTML to arrange elements, namely, cascading style sheets, which include grid and flexbox.

Long ago, wax replaced rubber cement for laying out newspaper and magazine pages. Wax was was a lot less messy, easier to apply, and didn't require thinner that made people high and gave them headaches. Using CSS is exactly the same. Tables are messy and give you headaches. They lock the content into a rigid layout that can't adapt to changing screen sizes.

One of the primary rules of web design is don't hard-code the styling into the HTML content -- CSS separates style from content, and that's why it's the right thing to use.

Comment: I don't think it's any one kind of problem. Accessibility is a concern, but It's not the only one. Tables are a maintenance problem, troubleshooting problem, adaptability problem, editing problem, and styling problem.

Comment: I think this is missing the point--in your example, wax replaced rubber cement. However, tables haven't been replaced (there is still a use for them). Also you say tables and layout aren't the same thing--regardless of whether you should or shouldn't use tables, tables can in fact be used for layout so there is by definition no distinction. A div is layout, a span is layout, a footer is layout, etc

Comment: Yeah, a footer is not a layout. It's an element that gets laid out. A layout is the whole thing. You lay out a page by putting all the elements in place. Yes, there are parts that have their own layouts, but don't confuse a div with a layout, or a table within a page as "the" layout.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a definition of "layout" that cannot functionally include <table> elements:

> "Layout" as it pertains to a web page is any visual element whose horizontal children can become vertical upon screen resizing, and vice versa (think responsive elements, i.e. Bootstrap).

<table> elements will never fit this definition, because table rows can never become horizontal, and table cells (of a given row) can never become vertical.

Comment: This is a completely nonsensical definition of the term with no supporting evidence as to why it was chosen.

Comment: @TylerH the evidence is in its logic; you can't turn a 3x1 table into a 1x3 table using CSS, but you can with 3 inline divs, making the statement "don't use tables for layout" easier to understand, since you *can't* use tables for that purpose. Imagine a web page with 3 primary sections: left sidebar, main content, and right sidebar. If the web page were made responsive, these sections would become vertical on a mobile device. If those 3 sections were made out of a table with 3 columns, it could never be responsive.

Comment: There is no logic in defining the word 'layout' in terms of whether an arbitrary object within can be rotated 90 degrees. Also, you can turn a 3x1 table into a 1x3 table with a little effort and some media queries.